# Bind a new function to various elements on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This *might* be a dupe, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. What I want is to bind a function to a named-class element on a page, then in later script, call a function against those regions. Specifically, I want to call something like (in the example below)...

```
$.each( $(".saveRegion"), function( idx, ele ){
    var valsToSave = $(ele).getValuesToSave();
    // shove the values to save into some construct
    // but only for the controls inside the two divs classed as "saveRegion"
});
```

My page is a set of conditional includes in the Pug file. The reason that's important, is that the individual page includes might not have the same sets of controls, but that region, or parent div's children nodes, are considered a set of information. Think of a form with address information that might be a region, and gender, eye color, and height that might be a region, all included as separate Pug files if the form in question needs that information. The parent page just wants to ask all the regions "give me your information so I can compile and save it", and each of those includes should be able to respond to that.

I'm probably overdoing it, huh?

```
div.sampleRegions
    if user.height == "tall"
        include ./userTall.pug
    if user.something == "another value"
        include .anotherPage.pug
    if user.hair == "brown"
        include ./userBrownHair.pug
```

The html in question might look like:

```
<div id="sampleRegions">
   <div class="saveRegion">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtUserName" type="text">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtPhone" type="text">
   </div>
   <div>
       <input class="form-control" id="favoriteColor" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="saveRegion">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtCountry" type="text">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtLanguage" type="text">
   </div>
</div>
```

So, I want to bind a function like getValuesToSave() to a div, then write the specifics for that div's getValuesToSave() function. I'm using Pug (formerly Jade) to draw forms based on certain user-specific settings, so the page includes I'm using can each know how to get and return the data for their specific page sections via some prototypical function. I hope this is making sense.

This would be a simple matter of an abstract class or a function override in any other language that supports it. I wrote C# server side stuff for systems processing for like 15 years, and this is trivial there. I am sure I'm just missing something super simple. Thanks!

Comment: Further clarification: the stuff inside the divs tagged as saveRegion might not always be a simple text box, so that's why each should have its own function to return or save values in a consistent format.

Comment: These functions would just be executing when certain mouse Events occur. For instance in vanilla JS `function predefinedFunction(){ this.style.background = '#000'; }; document.getElementById('someId').onclick = predefinedFunction;`. So `this` in an EventHandling function refers to the Element itself, therefore `this` would be automatically bound to the Element upon assignment, and you can just use the same function like `document.getElementById('anotherElementId').onblur = predfinedFunciton`. Note that the Event Object is automatically passed to an EventHandling function.

Comment: Using my `predefinedFunction` from above... you can also bind a function's `this` value by using call like `predefinedFunction.call(document.getElementById('someId'))`. Less backward compatible, you can also `var run = predefinedFunction.bind(document.getElementById('someId'));` then when you call `run()` the `this` value of `predefinedFunction` will be your Element. By the way, `predefinedFunction` would not really need to be predefined if using the function syntax. Of course, if you assign the function to a var it would need to be predefined.

Comment: Oh! I like that. I'll tinker. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 1):

You are able to use jQuery plugins for this purpose.

Example is available [here](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/).

Comment: but I can't do something like $(".saveRegion").fn.onSave = function(){....}, or better, $("#saveUserAddress").fn.onSave = function(){...}, right?

I feel like that would solve 100% of my issues in each of the includes. Then the outer page could simply do something like: $.each( $(".saveRegion"), function( idx, ele ){ var results = $(ele).onSave(); });

Answer (score 1):

You could go with a simple function which looks for all kind of input elements inside a specified elements and maps their values to objects of type `{ [nameByAttribute]: value }`.

Like this:

```js
function getValues(selector, keyAttr) {
  var INPUTS = ['textarea', 'input', 'select'].join();
  var BOOL_INPUTS = ['checkbox', 'radio'];
  var NUMBER_INPUTS = ['range', 'number'];
  var regions = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  
  return regions.map(function(region) {
    var values = [].slice.call(region.querySelectorAll(INPUTS));
    return values.map(function(element, index) {
      var type = element.getAttribute('type');
      var key = element.getAttribute(keyAttr) || index;
      var value = element.value;
      if(BOOL_INPUTS.indexOf(type) > -1) value = element.checked;
      if(NUMBER_INPUTS.indexOf(type) > -1) value = +element.value;
      return { [key]: value };
    });
  });
}

document.querySelector('#save').addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log(getValues('.saveRegion', 'id'));
});
```

```html
<div id="sampleRegions">
   <div class="saveRegion">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtUserName" type="radio">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtPhone" type="checkbox">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtPhone" type="range">
       <select idd="language">
          <option>EN</option>
          <option>DE</option>
          <option>FR</option>
       </select>
   </div>
   <div>
       <input class="form-control" id="favoriteColor" type="text">
   </div>
   <div class="saveRegion">
       <input class="form-control" id="txtCountry" type="text" value="textInput">
       <textarea class="form-control" id="txtLanguage">textArea</textarea>
   </div>
   <button id="save">save</button>
</div>
```

This could be easily extended to take a mapping as input, which defines how certain inputs should be handled.

Comment: I think, re-reading my question, I wasn't clear enough. To start at the beginning:

* My page is just a Pug file with a bunch of conditional includes. To p-code it:

if user.height == "tall"
    include ./userTall.pug
if user.hair == "brown"
    include ./userBrownHair.pug

Then, a single save button at the bottom of the page:

button.btn.btn-primary#saveAll Save

And in each of the include files, I'd like to have a function defined on each of the parent divs that knows how to read the child divs' values, and return them.

Probably can't do this, the more I think on it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think what I'm going to do is just add a function to each of the include pages that knows how to return an object containing the values for that region's salient controls, and name it based on the region name or something else to ensure uniqueness. Something like:

In Include-page-1

```
<div class="saveRegion" saveFunc="saveNameAddressRegion()">
    <input id="val1" ..../>
    <input id="val2" ..../>
    <input..../>
</div>

<script>
function saveNameAddressRegion(){
    // stupid-simple example
    return { val1: $("#val1").val(), val2 : $("#val2").val() };
}
</script>
```

Or in Jade/Pug template:

```
.saveRegion(saveFunc="saveNameAddressRegion()")
    input#val1(type="text")
    input#val2(type="text")
    input#val3(type="text")

script.
    function saveNameAddressRegion(){
        // stupid-simple example
        return { val1: $("#val1").val(), val2 : $("#val2").val() };
    }
```

Then in Include-page-2

```
<div class="saveRegion" saveFunc="doItAgain()">
    <select id="selEyeColor">
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="brown">Brown</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
function doItAgain(){
    return { eyeColor : $("#selEyeColor option:selected").val() };
}
</script>
```

And then the enclosing/parent page can just do something like:

```
include ./Include-Page-1.pug
include ./Include-Page-2.pug

script.
$.each(".saveRegion", function( idx, ele ){
    var vals = [];
    vals.push( eval( $(ele).attr("saveFunc") ) );
    // process them or whatever here.
});
```

This lets me get to a point where each Include file has a way of returning its values that may or may not be in some complicated on-screen form, control layout, etc. The parent page can always expect a simplified object with values, without knowing anything at all about each of the include-page layouts, design, contents, etc.

(( shrug ))